# Derive LM test for linearity

Tags: time-series, self-study, nonlinear-regression

I am studying nonlinear models. And I try to derive LM test for nonlinear model against well-specified parametric linear models

[image]

The book gives score vector $s(\theta)$ and information matrix $I(\theta)$.

I know that

$$LM= s(\theta)’ I^{-1}(\theta) s(\theta)$$

$$(1\sigma^2) [ZZ’H’H-ZHH’Z’]^{-1}[\epsilon’HZZ’H’\epsilon]$$

I found LM test statistic up to this point. But from here, I cannot drive the equation (10.18).

But I could not find the equation (10.18) through this formula.

Please let me know how to derive the equation (10.18). Thank you.